# Loading model with texture in GLGravity Iphone project

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

I have downloaded the GLGravity project from apple site. I tried loading a new model to display instead of teapot. the model is loading but without using the defined textures.

I am trying to display the model using the following code but unable to display the texture.

// in setupView method

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, camaro_objVerts);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, camaro_objNormals);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, camaro_objTexCoords);
```

in drawView method

```
// draw data
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, camaro_objNumVerts);
```

I have also tried disabling lightning, but the model loads with white color and without texture.

Comment: How do you set up your texture?  That is, what does the code look like around your `glBindTexture()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled `GL_TEXTURE_2D`? It should look like this (+ texture binding):

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: I have a 3d model. I got ".obj", ".mtl" file which i have converted using obj2opengl.pl to ".h" file.

Comment: can you please point to some directions where i can load a header file with all verticals, normals, text coords with a material files loading textures from different images.

Comment: @Hanuman: I have no idea how Apple loads the data from the .h file, and its not a real format either. However, there are examples that cover loading textures, but you have to load it yourself. And the material stuff of .mtl files can't be applied easily, you have to write some sort of parser which creates a shader out of this (or try to emulate it via the ffp, depending on what kind of renderer you are using)